# Can't update old code to Three.js 88

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I've been stuck for the last two weeks on updating the threejs_mousepick.html example from an old THREE.js release to the current one. Oh, yeah, I am a newbie to programming.

I've created a Fiddle, hopping someone would spend sometime helping me. CANNON.js is a great API and it is sad to see that examples are so old/unusable with today's THREE.js. I understand it is a lot of work and I am feeling to help but I need some help first. So, if @schteppe you read this, get in touch: I am willing to spend some time working on this.

Comment: Here's the link:   https://jsfiddle.net/f4j64L91/1/

Comment: Check the log in console, there are several useful messages. And read about [`THREE.Raycaster()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster).

Comment: I did. I know how to use Three.js raycaster, I tried to replace the function a few things but haven't succeeded... yet. This code is complex, nested. I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle in my answer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as broad as the question.

Using of `THREE.Raycaster()` and `THREE.Plane()` simplifies the things a lot. It allows to rid off such functions as `projectOntoPlane`, `findNearestIntersectingObject`, `getRayCasterFromScreenCoord`, and shortens the `setScreenPerpCenter` function (its name is ridiculous, but I left it as it was) to just one line.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/wpfn1Lbg/) example r87

[image]

`gplane` is `THREE.Plane()`:

```
var gplane = new THREE.Plane(), gplaneNormal = new THREE.Vector3();
```

As it written in the descripting comment, we create a virtual plane, which we move our point of joint on.

```
function setScreenPerpCenter(point) {
  gplane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(gplaneNormal.subVectors(camera.position, point).normalize(), point);
}
```

Here, we set our plane from a normal and a coplanar point, where the normal is a normalized vector of subtraction between the position of the camera and the point of click on the cube, and the point is that point of click itself. Read about that method [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Plane)

Comment: Man, thank you. I always confused with these functions and could not be sure of how to use them or not. I'll spend time tonight to learn from your code. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the answer as accepted, if it solves your problem )

Comment: Hopefully you'll read this, prisoner849, because I have some problem understanding l.165: (I changed gplane for refPlane, for length purposes, I cant type it)

From what I understand:
1) refPlaneNormal is assigned new values from "camera.position" - "point" (which is taken from the click event; I have Vector3 type of varialble.
2) Then refPlaneNormal is normalized, which means refPlaneNormal / 1; Here I also have a vector3.
3) After solving setFromNormalAndCoplamarPoint with my "2) vector2" and my click event point, I get a plane which name is refPlane.

Is that how you read this?

Comment: Thank you, again. All this is a bit new to me but I'm starting to get a hold on it.